# A question about random permutations and the probability of their fixed points

Tags: probability, self-study, randomness

[image]

I have started off by listing all the random permutations as

(1 2 3)

(1 3 2)

(2 3 1)

(2 1 3)

(3 2 1)

(3 1 2)

I have shown that the probability a random permutation has at least one fixed point by calculating

1 - Pr(less than 1 fixed point) = 1 - 1/3 = 2/3 (obtaining 1/3 because there are 2/6 random permutations that do not have a fixed point).

For the second part of the question I have approached it by drawing a venn diagram which is mutually exhaustive but not mutually exclusive but my probabilities aren't adding up to 1 which I'm assuming means I'm approaching it in the wrong way and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).